# NSFetchedResultsController and UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableViewController fetching a collection of objects A with a NSFetchedResultsController.

This works well and if these objet A's properties are updated, the UITableViewCell for A reflects the change.

**The problem:** this object has a relationship A->[B1, B2, B3...]. The cell is using some of the B's properties in its display. If I update one of the B's properties, the UITableViewCell doesn't reflects the change.

How can I make the cell change when I update one of the B, without reloading the whole tableview. Is there a way to mark an object to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try James answer.
I also found that using refreshObject:mergeChanges: on A would trigger reloading of this object. Is it ok to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could register for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` and examine the `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` value in the `userInfo` dictionary. If one of the updated objects is B1, B2, B3, etc., then follow its inverse relationship to determine which A object has "changed." You can determine the index of the "changed" A by finding it in `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `fetchedObjects` array. And then, finally, call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on the `UITableView`.